# Issue Cookies In NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have this problem with NodeJS Cookies.

my code :

```
var username= req.param('id')

res.send(req.cookies.username)
```

NodeJS thinks i want a cookie that it calls username.

But I need a cookie that its name is equal to My ID in url.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your correct code should look like this:

```
res.send(req.cookies[username]);
```

[Property Accessors - Bracket notation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation)

Comment: @user3719259 No, I haven't a yahoo ID. (Such comments, asking for a users Facebook, Yahoo or whatever account are basically not allowed on SO, and will be flagged as too chatty)

Comment: could you please help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66892622/get-cookie-on-front-end