# Get cookie on front-end

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nestjs

I use on back-end  nodejs(nestjs). From the server i send the cookies after login:

```js
res.cookie('token', 'token', {
  httpOnly: true
});
```

And this is my cors setting `app.enableCors({credentials: true });`;

As front-end i use reactjs. After login the server sent the cookies here:
[image]

But i need to get the cookies here:
[image]

Why i don't get the cookies in the place where i showed and how to get them there to save them even o reloading the page?

Comment: This is not how `httpOnly` cookies work. The browser will persist them automatically and send them with every request. Also you can't access `httpOnly` cookies in client javascript code. This is a security feature so injected scripts can't steal the cookies.

Comment: @trixn, why i did not get the cookies on the last image?

Comment: @trixn ,could you help?

Comment: You should see that cookie in application/storage dev tools with a mark in the "H" column.
Try `res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", ["secure=mhm; HttpOnly", "notSecure=yeah"]);`
It should set one HttpOnly cookie and one regular.

Comment: hello, what is your node version and do you use the yarn now?

Comment: @Glisten, v14.13.0, i use npm.

Comment: @AdrianBienias, even if i set what you suggest, i get cookies only in the first image but not in the second. How to send cookies on UI and to get them in the tab from the last image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason the cookie is not persisted in the frontend is that you are probably not setting the `withCredentials` on your frontend request. An example with axios would be:

```js
axios.post('http://localhost:3001', {}, { withCredentials: true })
```

An example with fetch is:

```js
fetch(url, {
    method,
    headers: { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
    },
    credentials: 'include'  
}
```

Note: For security reasons you must have explicitly specified the origin on your backend CORS configuration otherwise you will get the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3001/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

To do that with nest.js/express you can pass:

```js
app.enableCors({
   credentials: true,
   origin: ['http://localhost:3002', 'your-production-domain'] 
});
```

Comment: i set what you specified but also the same issue.

Comment: Did you not receive any error on the console about cors?  You probably misspelled or misplaced the frontend `withCredentials` option.

Comment: i don't receive any errors in the console. I get even the cookies but not in the right place. Its like i described in the question. What could be the issue?

Comment: could be the issue if my nest js application use a port ex: 3000, and my react another ex: 4000?

Comment: The reason is that you have not configured withCredentials AJAX option. It is required when you are doing cross orirgin requests and you want to send/receive cookies. Since your frontend and backend are on different ports then you need this option. What you are describing confirms to me exactly that the option missing. You would see the cookie on the network tab but it would not be set and persisted.

Comment: this is how  headers look: `fetch(url, {
    method,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      credentials: 'include',
    },` i use native fetch.

Comment: I updated my example to show the way of using fetch with that option. Have you put the credentials option inside the headers by mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you just want to be able to get those cookies on your front side in "Cookies", set:

```js
res.cookie('token', 'token', {
  httpOnly: false
});
```

Then, you'll get it in `document.cookie`, as usual.